# Is it safe to access a default argument by reference?

Tags: c++

I have a function that looks like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ...
};

void some_function(const SomeClass& arg = SomeClass());
```

The function `some_function` accesses its argument by reference and has a default value. Is it safe to do this, or will the reference be invalid when I call the function without an argument?

Comment: It is a surprise for me to see a 14K user asking this question!! (no offense)

Comment: @mavric: Who says that rep was earned answering C++ questions? A person's rep is pretty irrelevant- trust me, I'm 26k!

Comment: @mavric I'm a Java / Scala programmer, it's been a long time that I've written any serious C++ program, so my C++ is a bit rusty. I'm just playing with it again as a hobby.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yeah, I see it now!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. A const reference bound to a temporary extends the life of that temporary to the lifetime of the reference. The same is true of rvalue references.

Answer (score 4):

It will be valid.  The lifetime of the temporary used as a default value is a superset of the lifetime of the function call.  This is also no different than if you had passed in a temporary explicitly (default arguments are basically syntactic sugar, saving you from typing, but behave more or less identically to arguments passed explicitly.